# Click button reveal reclick vanish

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a button that makes a div appear on click and disappear on reclick. I can get it to disappear on click but not reappear on reclick. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function vanish1() {
  if (document.getElementById('priceCheck1').style.display.value == "none") {
    document.getElementById('priceCheck1').style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('priceCheck1').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="button" class="input_button" name="onestarbtn" value="One Star" onclick="vanish1()"/>
</div>
<div id="priceCheck1">
        test1
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no value property for `display` value(in the `if` statement), it is a string so

```
function vanish1() {
    var el = document.getElementById('priceCheck1');
    if (el.style.display == "none") {
        el.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mxv5o5fn/)

Answer (score 0):

When trying to access an element's current style, you should use the `getComputedStyle()` method.

#### Try it:

```js
function vanish1() {
    var p = document.getElementById('priceCheck1');
    p.style.display = (getComputedStyle(p).display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" class="input_button" name="onestarbtn" value="One Star" onclick="vanish1()" />
</div>
<div id="priceCheck1">test1</div>
```